# convert an enum to another type of enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum of for example '`Gender`' (`Male =0 , Female =1`) and I have another enum from a service which has its own Gender enum (`Male =0 , Female =1, Unknown =2`)

My question is how can I write something quick and nice to convert from their enum to mine?

Comment: What do you want to convert "unknown" to?

Comment: You can typecast the enum to other enum types when both have the same values see http://ideone.com/7lgvgf

Comment: If only this worked in Java...

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Using an extension method works quite neatly, when using the two conversion methods suggested by Nate:

```
public static class TheirGenderExtensions
{
    public static MyGender ToMyGender(this TheirGender value)
    {
        // insert switch statement here
    }
}

public static class MyGenderExtensions
{
    public static TheirGender ToTheirGender(this MyGender value)
    {
        // insert switch statement here
    }
}
```

Obviously there's no need to use separate classes if you don't want to. My preference is to keep extension methods grouped by the classes/structures/enumerations they apply to.

Answer (score 332):

Given `Enum1 value = ...`, then if you mean by name:

```
Enum2 value2 = (Enum2) Enum.Parse(typeof(Enum2), value.ToString());
```

If you mean by numeric value, you can usually just cast:

```
Enum2 value2 = (Enum2)value;
```

(with the cast, you might want to use `Enum.IsDefined` to check for valid values, though)

Comment: This is the better answer

Comment: Here is a version that uses `Enum.Tryparse`:

`Enum2 value2 = Enum.TryParse(value.ToString(), out Enum2 outValue) ? outValue : Enum2.Unknown;`

This will allow you to handle input values that don't exist in `Enum2` without needing to call `Enum.IsDefined` or catch `ArgumentException`s thrown by `Enum.Parse`. Note that the order of the parameters is more or less reversed from `Enum.Parse`.

Comment: Yes, this should be the accepted answer IMO

Answer (score 64):

Just cast one to int and then cast it to the other enum (considering that you want the mapping done based on value):

```
Gender2 gender2 = (Gender2)((int)gender1);
```

Comment: Although it's unlikely to see it 'in the wild', and it is highly unlikely to be the case for genders, there could exist some enum that is backed by a `long` (or `ulong`) rather than an `int` which has members defined that are above `int.MaxValue` (or below `int.MinValue`), in which case the cast to `int` could overflow and you'd end up with an undefined enum value which should be defined.

Comment: of course. the correct way would be (Gender2)((insert underlying type here)gender1) but i think the example above gives the right idea so i won't change it.

Comment: This requires the two enums to have the same values in the same order.  While it solves this specific problem, this is really brittle and I wouldn't use this for enum mapping in general.

Comment: well.... duh! . Mapping needs to be done based on something. In this case the mapping is on integral value. For mapping base on name you need different code. For another kind of mapping something else. Noone said this is "for enum mapping in general" and that case does not exist unless you can try to specify what "mapping in general" means

Answer (score 27):

If we have:

```
enum Gender
{
    M = 0,
    F = 1,
    U = 2
}
```

and

```
enum Gender2
{
    Male = 0,
    Female = 1,
    Unknown = 2
}
```

We can safely do

```
var gender = Gender.M;
var gender2   = (Gender2)(int)gender;
```

Or even

```
var enumOfGender2Type = (Gender2)0;
```

If you want to cover the case where an enum on the right side of the '=' sign has more values than the enum on the left side - you will have to write your own method/dictionary to cover that as others suggested.

Comment: Your answer is like asking a question!? If yes this is not an answer and if no there is a [similar answer above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1818786/4519059) ;).

Answer (score 24):

To be thorough I normally create a pair of functions, one that takes Enum 1 and returns Enum 2 and another that takes Enum 2 and returns Enum 1. Each consists of a case statement mapping inputs to outputs and the default case throws an exception with a message complaining about an unexpected value.

In this particular case you could take advantage of the fact that the integer values of Male and Female are the same, but I'd avoid that as it's hackish and subject to breakage if either enum changes in the future.

Comment: +1 I have seen many developers giving up to the urge of using integer value of enums to convert them but this is very error prone. The old school method of writing 2 functions has proven its worth over time...

Answer (score 16):

I wrote this answer because I believe there are fundamental issues with the majority of answers already provided, and the ones that are acceptable are incomplete.

**Mapping by enum integer value**

This approach is bad simply because it assumes that the integer values of both `MyGender` and `TheirGender` will always remain comparable. In practice, it is very rare that you can guarantee this even within a single project, let alone a separate service.

The approach we take should be something that can be used for other enum-mapping cases. We should never assume that one enum identically relates to another - especially when we may not have control over one or another.

**Mapping by enum string value**

This is a little better, as `MyGender.Male` will still convert to `TheirGender.Male` even if the integer representation is changed, but still not ideal.

I would discourage this approach as it assumes the name values will not change, and will always remain identical. Considering future enhancements, you cannot guarantee that this will be the case; consider if `MyGender.NotKnown` was added. It is likely that you would want this to map to `TheirGender.Unknown`, but this would not be supported.

Also, it is generally bad to assume that one enum equates to another by name, as this might not be the case in some contexts. As mentioned earlier, an ideal approach would work for other enum-mapping requirements.

**Explicitly mapping enums**

This approach explictly maps `MyGender` to `TheirGender` using a switch statement.

This is better as:

- Covers the case where the underlying integer value changes.
- Covers the case where the enum names changes (i.e. no assumptions - the developer will need to update the code to handle the scenario  - good).
- Handles cases where enum values cannot be mapped.
- Handles cases where new enum values are added and cannot be mapped by default (again, no assumptions made - good).
- Can easily be updated to support new enum values for either `MyGender` or `TheirGender`.
- The same approach can be taken for all enum mapping requirements.

Assuming we have the following enums:

```
public enum MyGender
{
    Male = 0,
    Female = 1,
}

public enum TheirGender
{
    Male = 0,
    Female = 1,
    Unknown = 2,
}
```

We can create the following function to "*convert from their enum to mine*":

```
public MyGender GetMyGender(TheirGender theirGender)
{
    switch (theirGender)
    {
        case TheirGender.Male:
            return MyGender.Male;

        case TheirGender.Female:
            return MyGender.Female;

        default:
            throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException(nameof(theirGender), (int)theirGender, typeof(TheirGender));
    }
}
```

A previous answer suggested returning a nullable enum (`TheirGender?`) and returning null for any unmatched input. This is bad; null is not the same as an unknown mapping. If the input cannot be mapped, an exception should be thrown, else the method should be named more explictly to the behaviour:

```
public TheirGender? GetTheirGenderOrDefault(MyGender myGender)
{
    switch (myGender)
    {
        case MyGender.Male:
            return TheirGender.Male;
            
        case MyGender.Female:
            return TheirGender.Female;
            
        default:
            return default(TheirGender?);
    }
}
```

**Additional considerations**

If it is likely that this method will be required more than once in various parts of the solution, you could consider creating an extension method for this:

```
public static class TheirGenderExtensions
{
    public static MyGender GetMyGender(this TheirGender theirGender)
    {
        switch (theirGender)
        {
            case TheirGender.Male:
                return MyGender.Male;

            case TheirGender.Female:
                return MyGender.Female;

            default:
                throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException(nameof(theirGender), (int)theirGender, typeof(TheirGender));
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using C#8, you can use the [syntax for switch expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions) and [expression bodies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#methods) to neaten up the code:

```
public static class TheirGenderExtensions
{
    public static MyGender GetMyGender(this TheirGender theirGender)
        => theirGender switch
        {
            TheirGender.Male => MyGender.Male,
            TheirGender.Female => MyGender.Female,
            _ => throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException(nameof(theirGender), (int)theirGender, typeof(TheirGender))
        };
}
```

If you will only ever be mapping the enums within a single class, then an extension method may be overkill. In this case, the method can be declared within the class itself.

Furthermore, if the mapping will only ever take place within a single method, then you can declare this as a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions):

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetMyGender(TheirGender.Male));
    Console.WriteLine(GetMyGender(TheirGender.Female));
    Console.WriteLine(GetMyGender(TheirGender.Unknown));
    
    static MyGender GetMyGender(TheirGender theirGender)
        => theirGender switch
        {
            TheirGender.Male => MyGender.Male,
            TheirGender.Female => MyGender.Female,
            _ => throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException(nameof(theirGender), (int)theirGender, typeof(TheirGender))
        };
}
```

[Here's a dotnet fiddle link with the above example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yURjZh).

**tl;dr:**

Do not:

- Map enums by integer value
- Map enums by name

Do:

- Map enums explicitly using a switch statement
- Throw an exception when a value cannot be mapped rather than returning null
- Consider using extension methods

Comment: Fantastic suggestions! We're mapping third party enums into our own system agnostic mappings. And I cannot iterate enough times how 3rd parties API change (can, do,and  will change!) You want change to be a hard trackable error *EVERY* time (see this answer's use of InvalidEnumArgumentException). I can't think of a case where we would not be MORE hurt if we acted as per normal on enums by an int mapping. Its bad enough a name's ambiguous meaning can alter intended system behavior. Third party systems are the devil at times... tl;dr When there is no exact match, toss an error and wake up a dev.

Answer (score 15):

You could write a simple generic extension method like this

```
public static T ConvertTo<T>(this object value)            
    where T : struct,IConvertible
{
    var sourceType = value.GetType();
    if (!sourceType.IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("Source type is not enum");
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("Destination type is not enum");
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: It doesn't cover the case of missing values as suggested in above answers.
You should modify this extension method covering that case too.

Answer (score 9):

you could write a simple function like the following:

```
public static MyGender ConvertTo(TheirGender theirGender)
{
    switch(theirGender)
    {
        case TheirGender.Male:
            break;//return male
        case TheirGender.Female:
            break;//return female
        case TheirGender.Unknown:
            break;//return whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: this isn't a function. expected 'MyGender' and you are return 'void'

Answer (score 7):

Here's an extension method version if anyone is interested

```
public static TEnum ConvertEnum<TEnum >(this Enum source)
    {
        return (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), source.ToString(), true);
    }

// Usage
NewEnumType newEnum = oldEnumVar.ConvertEnum<NewEnumType>();
```

Comment: Doesn't that imply both enumerations have same numeric values?

Comment: No, this is converting by name by string. So Enum.Foo (1) will translate to Enum2.Foo (2) even though their numeric values are different.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static TEnum ConvertByName<TEnum>(this Enum source, bool ignoreCase = false) where TEnum : struct
{
    // if limited by lack of generic enum constraint
    if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("enumeration type required.");
    }

    TEnum result;
    if (!Enum.TryParse(source.ToString(), ignoreCase, out result))
    {
        throw new Exception("conversion failure.");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In case when the enum members have different values, you can apply something like this:

```
public static MyGender? MapToMyGender(this Gender gender)
{
    return gender switch
    {
        Gender.Male => MyGender.Male,
        Gender.Female => MyGender.Female,
        Gender.Unknown => null,
        _ => throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException($"Invalid gender: {gender}")
    };
}
```

Then you can call: `var myGender = gender.MapToMyGender();`

**Update:**
This previous code works only with C# 8.
For older versions of C#, you can use the switch statement instead of the switch expression:

```
public static MyGender? MapToMyGender(this Gender gender)
{
    switch (gender)
    {
        case Gender.Male: 
            return MyGender.Male;
        case Gender.Female:
            return MyGender.Female;
        case Gender.Unknown:
            return null;
        default:
            throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException($"Invalid gender: {gender}")
    };
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This code works only with C# 8. Please highlight this information in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a set extension methods a while back that work for several different kinds of `Enum`s. One in particular works for what you are trying to accomplish and handles `Enum`s with the `FlagsAttribute` as well as `Enum`s with different underlying types.

```
public static tEnum SetFlags<tEnum>(this Enum e, tEnum flags, bool set, bool typeCheck = true) where tEnum : IComparable
{
    if (typeCheck)
    {
        if (e.GetType() != flags.GetType())
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument is not the same type as this instance.", "flags");
    }

    var flagsUnderlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(tEnum));

    var firstNum = Convert.ToUInt32(e);
    var secondNum = Convert.ToUInt32(flags);

    if (set)
        firstNum |= secondNum;

    else
        firstNum &= ~secondNum;

    var newValue = (tEnum)Convert.ChangeType(firstNum, flagsUnderlyingType);

    if (!typeCheck)
    {
        var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(tEnum));
        var lastValue = (tEnum)values.GetValue(values.Length - 1);

        if (newValue.CompareTo(lastValue) > 0)
            return lastValue;
    }

    return newValue;
}
```

From there you can add other more specific extension methods.

```
public static tEnum AddFlags<tEnum>(this Enum e, tEnum flags) where tEnum : IComparable
{
    SetFlags(e, flags, true);
}

public static tEnum RemoveFlags<tEnum>(this Enum e, tEnum flags) where tEnum : IComparable
{
    SetFlags(e, flags, false);
}
```

This one will change types of `Enum`s like you are trying to do.

```
public static tEnum ChangeType<tEnum>(this Enum e) where tEnum : IComparable
{
    return SetFlags(e, default(tEnum), true, false);
}
```

Be warned, though, that you CAN convert between any `Enum` and any other `Enum` using this method, even those that do not have flags. For example:

```
public enum Turtle
{
    None = 0,
    Pink,
    Green,
    Blue,
    Black,
    Yellow
}

[Flags]
public enum WriteAccess : short
{
   None = 0,
   Read = 1,
   Write = 2,
   ReadWrite = 3
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WriteAccess access = WriteAccess.ReadWrite;
    Turtle turtle = access.ChangeType<Turtle>();
}
```

The variable `turtle` will have a value of `Turtle.Blue`.

However, there is safety from undefined `Enum` values using this method. For instance:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Turtle turtle = Turtle.Yellow;
    WriteAccess access = turtle.ChangeType<WriteAccess>();
}
```

In this case, `access` will be set to `WriteAccess.ReadWrite`, since the `WriteAccess` `Enum` has a maximum value of 3.

Another side effect of mixing `Enum`s with the `FlagsAttribute` and those without it is that the conversion process will not result in a 1 to 1 match between their values.

```
public enum Letters
{
    None = 0,
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F,
    G,
    H
}

[Flags]
public enum Flavors
{
    None = 0,
    Cherry = 1,
    Grape = 2,
    Orange = 4,
    Peach = 8
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Flavors flavors = Flavors.Peach;
    Letters letters = flavors.ChangeType<Letters>();
}
```

In this case, `letters` will have a value of `Letters.H` instead of `Letters.D`, since the backing value of `Flavors.Peach` is 8. Also, a conversion from `Flavors.Cherry | Flavors.Grape` to `Letters` would yield `Letters.C`, which can seem unintuitive.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Justin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3434365/justin) answer above I came up with this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts Enum Value to different Enum Value (by Value Name) See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31993512/6500501.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEnum">The type of the enum to convert to.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">The source enum to convert from.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"></exception>
    public static TEnum ConvertTo<TEnum>(this Enum source)
    {
        try
        {
            return (TEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), source.ToString(), ignoreCase: true);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException aex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException
            (
                $"Could not convert {source.GetType().ToString()} [{source.ToString()}] to {typeof(TEnum).ToString()}", aex
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that's an old question and have a lot of answers, However I find that using a switch statement as in the accepted answer is somewhat cumbersome, so here are my 2 cents:

My personal favorite method is to use a dictionary, where the key is the source enum and the value is the target enum - so in the case presented on the question my code would look like this:

```
var genderTranslator = new Dictionary<TheirGender, MyGender>();
genderTranslator.Add(TheirGender.Male, MyGender.Male);
genderTranslator.Add(TheirGender.Female, MyGender.Female);
genderTranslator.Add(TheirGender.Unknown, MyGender.Unknown);

// translate their to mine    
var myValue = genderTranslator[TheirValue];

// translate mine to their
var TheirValue = genderTranslator .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == myValue).Key;;
```

Of course, this can be wrapped in a static class and be used as an extension methods:

```
public static class EnumTranslator
{

    private static Dictionary<TheirGender, MyGender> GenderTranslator = InitializeGenderTranslator();

    private static Dictionary<TheirGender, MyGender> InitializeGenderTranslator()
    {
        var translator = new Dictionary<TheirGender, MyGender>();
        translator.Add(TheirGender.Male, MyGender.Male);
        translator.Add(TheirGender.Female, MyGender.Female);
        translator.Add(TheirGender.Unknown, MyGender.Unknown);
        return translator;
    }

    public static MyGender Translate(this TheirGender theirValue)
    {
        return GenderTranslator[theirValue];
    }

    public static TheirGender Translate(this MyGender myValue)
    {
        return GenderTranslator.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == myValue).Key;
    }

}
```

Comment: I like this approach as you may also enumerate both enumerations in order to populate the dictionary. (when they are in same order of course)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ToString() to convert the first enum to its name, and then Enum.Parse() to convert the string back to the other Enum. This will throw an exception if the value is not supported by the destination enum (i.e. for an "Unknown" value)

Answer (score 0):

For grins you can do this

```
public enum TestNum {
{
    [EnumConvert( NewType.AType )]
    Test1,

    [EnumConvert( NewType.BType )]
    Test2
}

public enum NewType {
    AType,
    BType
}

public static class EnumExtensions {
public static Enum GetEnum(this Enum value ) {
    var attribute = (EnumConvertAttribute)value.GetType()
        .GetField( value.ToString() )
        .GetCustomAttribute( false )
        .Where( a => a is EnumConvertAttribute
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if( attribute == null ) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }

    try {
        return attribute.TargetEnum;
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    }
}
```

}

public class EnumConvertAttribute : Attribute {
public Enum TargetEnum;

```
public EnumConvertAttribute( object e ) {
    TargetEnum = (Enum)e;
}
```

}

call:
var t1 = TestNum.Test2;
var t2 = t1.GetEnum();

t2 = NewType.BType;

It works, assuming you don't mind boxing. Converting enums a lot is not good practice anyways. You do get strong typing, you don't have 2 methods for conversions to create a bug eventually when maintaining, and your not praying that the string or int comparisons don't fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
Enum1 var1;
Enum2 var2;

var2 = Enum2.fromValue(var1.getValue())

public enum Enum2 {
    FEMALE("FEMALE"),
    MALE("MALE")
    private String value;

    public static Enum2 fromValue(String value) {
        for (Enum2 b : Enum2.values()) {
            if (b.value.equals(value)) {
                return b;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1818149/22817151) of [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell).

I wrote a [nuget library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kurnakov.EnumConverter).

Installation:

```
dotnet add package Kurnakov.EnumConverter
```

Code example:

```
var anotherGenderEnum = genderEnum.ToAnother<AnotherGenderEnum>();
```

More details you can find [here](https://github.com/kurnakovv/EnumConverter)