# Create new enum from existing enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have an existing enum

```
public enum BalanceType // existing enum
{
    Available,
    Phone,
    Commissary,
    Account,
    Reserve,
    Encumber,
    Debt,
    Held,
}
```

Now I want to create a new enum from it. The new one only contains two fields.

```
 public class IvrBalanceInfo
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public IvrBalanceType Type { get; set; }
    public IvrBalanceInfo(BalanceInfo info, BalanceType type)
    {
        Amount = info.Amount;
        //How to create the enum IvrBalanceType?
    }

    public enum IvrBalanceType // new enum
    {
        Available,
        Phone,
    }
}
```

My question is how to map it quickly? I mean to convert the old one to new one. The old one is from the third party. There are too much elements. I only need two.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What do you mean? You can't _create_ an enum (apart from really ugly things like generating assemblies using reflection emit). But more important, you should not have to do such things. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Are you asking how to map one `enum` to the other?

Comment: Uhm, do you mean "how can I convert from `BalanceType` to `IvrBalanceType`"?

Comment: just use if else or switch....

Comment: Yes, I wan to convert it.  @Albireo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818131/convert-an-enum-to-another-type-of-enum

Comment: What do you wish to map `Commissary` etc to in `IvrBalanceType`?

Comment: You can do `Enum.TryParse<IvrBalanceType>(type.ToString(), true, out whatEver);`

Comment: @DavidArno, no. The old one is from the vendor. I don't need too much of them. I only need two of them and match them.

Comment: Then just do `Type = type == BalanceType.Available ? IvrBalanceType.Available : IvrBalanceType.Phone;`

Comment: We seem to have been too hasty in closing this, as you provided clarification via the comments. It's unlikely you'll get the five required re-open votes. I'd recommend you delete this question, then ask again. Make sure you clarify you want to map from one enum to the other, that you are only interested in `Available` and `Phone` and explain what should happen if `type` is of one of the other values.

Comment: Enums are integer types so quickest will be `NewEnumValue = OldEnumValue`. Another approach will be using `Enum.IsDefined` for checking if old enum's value defined in the new Enum

Comment: @DavidArno, it is open now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class IvrBalanceInfo
{
   public decimal Amount { get; set; }
   public IvrBalanceType Type { get; set; }
   public IvrBalanceInfo(BalanceInfo info, BalanceType type)
   {
      Amount = info.Amount;
      if (type == BalanceType.Available)
         Type = IvrBalanceType.Available;
      else if(type == BalanceType.Phone)
         Type = IvrBalanceType.Phone

      // here you have to handle the other values and set the default
      // values for the Type Property or it will take the default value
      // if you not set it
   }

   public enum IvrBalanceType // new enum
   {
       Available,
       Phone,
   }
}
```

the problem with the other solution is that it will throw an exception if the value of the `type` parameter was not one of the values `BalanceType.Available`, `BalanceType.Phone`

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

```
public class IvrBalanceInfo
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public IvrBalanceType Type { get; set; }
    public IvrBalanceInfo(BalanceInfo info, BalanceType type)
    {
        Amount = info.Amount;
        Type = (IvrBalanceType)(int)type;
    }

    public enum IvrBalanceType // new enum
    {
        Available,
        Phone,
    }
}
```

I believe you should check for value or get some default for other values.

Just ensured it compiles, haven't got time to check how it works.