# Is there a way to convert between a collection of custom enum to a collection of another custom enum?

Tags: c#, collections, enums

We already know we can [convert an enum to another type of enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818131/convert-an-enum-to-another-type-of-enum), so the following compiles:

```
public class EnumTest
{
   enum Enum1 { Foo };
   enum Enum2 { Foo };
   void Test () 
   {
       System.Enum e = new Enum2();   // compiles
       Enum1 e1 = (Enum1)new Enum2(); // compiles with an explicit cast
   }
}
```

But this doesn't compile:

```
public class EnumTest
{
   enum Enum1 { Foo };
   enum Enum2 { Foo };
   void Test () 
   {
       List<System.Enum> eList = new List<Enum2>();         // doesn't compile
       List<Enum1> e1List = (List<Enum1>)new List<Enum2>(); // doesn't compile
   }
}
```

Is that a [covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445631/still-confused-about-covariance-and-contravariance-in-out) issue? If not, is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Are you expecting `Enum1,Foo` to always equate to `Enum2.Foo`? What if `Enum1.Foo` is equal to integer 1 and `Enum2.Foo` is equal to integer 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a *co*-variance issue, it's a *variance* issue. Enums are value types and co-variance is not supported for value types. And `List<T>` is a `class`, not an `interface` or `delegate`. Co-variance is only supported for interfaces and delegates.

You have to cast/convert the elements in the lists:

```
List<Enum2> list2 = ...
List<System.Enum> eList = list2.Cast<System.Enum>().ToList();
```

But this of course results in a new list. `eList` is a different instance than `list2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast like that, `Enum1` and `Enum2` are completely different things. You can do it with some simple Linq though. For example:

```
List<Enum2> eList = new List<Enum2>
{ 
    Enum2.Foo 
};

List<Enum1> e1List = eList
    .Select(x => (Enum1)x)
    .ToList();
```

Note this is using a straight case, but you might want to use the conversion function from the question you linked.