# Converting one enum type to another by name

Tags: c#

I have a data entity with the property 'UserType' returned as an Enum and need to convert it to another.

The first enum is (with numbers based on values from the database):

```
  public enum UserType
    {
        Primary = 100001,
        Secondary = 100002,
        Other = 100003
    }
```

And this is what I want to convert it to:

```
    public enum UserType
    {
        Primary,
        Secondary,
        Other
    }
```

This is in order to set the UserType on this class:

```
public class UserData
    {
        public UserType UserType{ get; set; }
    }
```

Something like the following maybe?

```
 MemberType = MemberType(entity.MemberType.ReadValue())
```

Does anyone know the best way to do this please?

Comment: Preference: make a mapping that accepts an `OldUserType` and returns a `NewUserType`. Failing that, perhaps `Enum.Parse<NewUserType>(OldUserType.Primary.ToString());`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert an enum to another type of enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818131/convert-an-enum-to-another-type-of-enum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enum.Parse`/`Enum.TryParse`:

```
A.UserType ut1 = A.UserType.Primary;
B.UserData data = new B.UserData();
data.UserType = Enum.TryParse(typeof(B.UserType), ut1.ToString(), true, out object ut2) ? (B.UserType)ut2 : B.UserType.Other;
```

`A` and `B` are just the namespace i have used to differentiate both enums. To simluate it i have used classes:

```
public class A
{
    public enum UserType
    {
        Primary = 100001,
        Secondary = 100002,
        Other = 100003
    }
}

public class B
{
    public enum UserType
    {
        Primary,
        Secondary,
        Other
    }

    public class UserData
    {
        public UserType UserType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need it once or twice, honestly: I'd write it manually:

```cs
return value switch {
    Foo.A => Bar.A,
    Foo.B => Bar.B,
    Foo.C => Bar.C,
    _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value)),
};
```

In the more general case: something involving `ToString()` and `Enum.Parse`, for example:

```cs
static TTo ConvertEnumByName<TFrom, TTo>(TFrom value, bool ignoreCase = false)
        where TFrom : struct
        where TTo : struct
        => Enum.Parse<TTo>(value.ToString(), ignoreCase);
```